# How to integrate NLTK with Ironpython

Tags: c#, nlp, ironpython, nltk

I want to call NLTK functions in my C# program using Ironpython. But I am getting the error 'No module named nltk'.
I am using .net 4.0, Python 2.6 and Ironpython 2.7.
I know this question has been asked previously, but it does not explain the process properly.
Hope someone can help.
/Suralk

Comment: I hope this link helps http://blog.samibadawi.com/2010/03/open-source-nlp-in-c-35-using-nltk.html

Comment: The question is 6 years old, but Google still provides this post on top of results for "nltk .net" query. For those who are looking for solution to integrate NLTK with IronPython please check [NltkNet](https://github.com/nrcpp/NltkNet). Project сonstantly evolving.